# How can I pass variables from 2 separate forms on one cfm to another cfm in coldfusion?

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have 2 forms on one page that I need to pass to the same page to assemble a pdf. How can I do that? I have tried using a action="post" for one and action="get" for the other, but I can't get that to work. I have tried assigning one form to session variables, but I can't get that either. Any suggestions??

```
  <form name="formOne" id="formOne" method="post" action="#buildURL('goTothisPage.page')#">
        <input name="name" id="name"  autofocus="true" >
        <input name="address" id="address" >
```

Comment: What is the use case for not being able/willing to combine the forms into one form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try just creating one big form instead of 2 smaller forms if the action is going to be the same and go to the same .cfm page. (Just expand the scope of your  tags)

You can also create 2 "Submit" buttons (1 for each form) to make it appear as 2 separate forms, even though the buttons will submit the same form.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make them into one form. One of them has some jQuery that screws up when I combine the two.

Comment: Combine the forms and fix the jquery.

Comment: I am with Dan. It will be infinitely easier to combine the forms and fix the jQuery than to accomplish what is being asked.

Comment: OK, thanks for the input. I ended up just making it all one form.

Answer (score 0):

If it is required to have two separate `form`s in your html, it is also possible to forge the form values from one form into the other at the moment of the submit event.

HTML:

```
<form name="formOne" id="formOne" method="post">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" >
    <input name="address" id="addressHidden" type="hidden">
</form>
<form name="formTwo" id="formTwo" method="post">
    <input name="address" id="address" type="text">
    <input name="name" id="nameHidden" type="hidden" >
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formOne').submit(function(event){
        $('#addressHidden').val($('#address').val());
        return true;
    });
    // same for #formTwo
    $('#formTwo').submit(function(event){
        $('#nameHidden').val($('#name').val());
        return true;
    });
});
```